# Retrieve s:hidden value and add as a param to an url

Tags: struts

I have an hidden input field which value changes according to the option selected in a s:select in Struts 2. Then, there's a button that points to an action like loadData.action.

I would like to add to this action a parameter named item.id with the value of the hidden field as its value, a value changing each time I select a new option.

I've tried to use an s:param with an s:property inside and the name or the id of the s:hidden, but it doesn't print the value after the = sign.

How can I do to achieve this result? loadData.action?item.id=12 where 12 is the value of s:hidden name="item" id="item" ?

Comment: Provide Action link with all parameters in sequence

Comment: Also your `HTML` structure

Answer (score 0):

Please Provide complete **action link** and which value to be change also your `HTML` structure, so it will be easy to answer your question

Assuming your `HTML` structure's elements, I have tried to answer your question

You can change action using `jQuery` on **change** event of your `<s:select>`

Have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/shantaram/qy9rew4v/

```
$('#id-select').change( function () {
    var newAction = $('#id-form').prop('action');
    newAction = newAction.substring(0, newAction.lastIndexOf('='));
    $('#id-form').prop('action', newAction+"="+varItemId);
    //varItemId is value of your hidden field 
    //which you want to change Dynamically
});
```

provided:
**id-select** -> Id of your `<select>` element
**id-form** -> Id of your `<form>` element